# Callback on microsoft bot framework end

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, botframework, serverless-framework

I am developing a Chatbot using Microsoft Bot framework with nodejs, and I want to deploy this on aws lambda using serverless framework, but to do that, I need to call the lambda callback.

I cant find how I can have a callback when processing a message ends(saved data and sent all the necessary messages).

I tried to simulate the response, and call the callback, but it didnt work, microsoft bot framework continues processing the message, here is the current handler I have

```
'use strict';
const DynamoDbStorage = require('./dynamo-db-storage').DynamoDbStorage
let storage = new DynamoDbStorage()
const connector = require('./channel')(storage)

module.exports.message = (event, context, callback) => {
   connector.verifyBotFramework(context, getHandler(callback));
};

function getHandler(callback) {
   let status = 200
   return {
      status: (code) => { status = code },
      send: (data) => {
         const response = {
             statusCode: 200,
             body: JSON.stringify(data),
         };
         callback(null, response)
     }
   }
 }
```

And here is my channel.js

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
function getChannel(storage) {

    const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
        appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
        appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
    });


    const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, {
        storage: storage
    });

    //Bot logic
    //...

    return connector
}

module.exports = getChannel;
```

Comment: What does verifyBotFramework in ./channel do?

Comment: It returns the Connector from botframework, and in that file I have the UniversalBot and all the logic

Comment: It is what listen does, I took it from here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/bots/ChatConnector.ts#L106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you linked does not seem to call the send function on your res object. Have you tried adding an `end()` function to it that calls the `callback` function.

```
function getHandler(callback) {
    let status = 200
    return {
        status: (code) => { status = code },
        send: (data) => {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            };
            callback(null, response)
        },
        end: () => callback(null, "end called");
    }
 }
```